# What do you call a robotic joint that allows a robot to move its arm in any direction unlike the human arm?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a robotic joint that allows a robot to move its arm in any direction unlike the human arm? Is there a name to such joints? I am thinking there might be several types that would allow such freedom of movement, so just pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to show us a technical drawing to know which you mean exactly.  One possibility is a [*universal joint*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_joint):

[image]

This joint allows the joint to fully rotate as it bends, so it can go in any direction.  A similar device is a *ball-and-socket joint* (or just *ball joint*) which does not allow rotation but does allow the mobile piece to bend in any direction.

[image]